# Can Ant Design form validation be skipped upon clicking the submit button?

Tags: reactjs, antd

When submitting an AntD form (initiated by clicking submit button) it seems to run through validation of fields by default.  I am tracking validation with each form field change so it is unnecessary for my implementation.

Is there a baked-in way to skip/disable the form validation upon submission of the form in Ant Design?

Comment: can you share your Form implementation?

Comment: It's irrelevant for what I'm asking, so no.  I was just giving that for justification for why one may want to do what I'm asking.  This question could be asked for literally any of the examples on the antd form documentation page.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't give `Button` type `submit`, and add an `onClick` method (`handleSubmit` below) to the button, you can handle submitting on button click without form validation being run automatically.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Form, Input, Button, Checkbox } from "antd";
const layout = {
  labelCol: {
    span: 8
  },
  wrapperCol: {
    span: 16
  }
};
const tailLayout = {
  wrapperCol: {
    offset: 8,
    span: 16
  }
};

const Demo = () => {
  const [form] = Form.useForm();

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    // grab form values
    let form_vals = form.getFieldsValue();
    // perform the rest of submit logic here...
  };

  return (
    <Form
      form={form}
      {...layout}
      name="basic"
      initialValues={{
        remember: true
      }}
    >
      <Form.Item
        label="Username"
        name="username"
        rules={[
          {
            required: true,
            message: "Please input your username!"
          }
        ]}
      >
        <Input />
      </Form.Item>

      <Form.Item
        label="Password"
        name="password"
        rules={[
          {
            required: true,
            message: "Please input your password!"
          }
        ]}
      >
        <Input.Password />
      </Form.Item>

      <Form.Item {...tailLayout} name="remember" valuePropName="checked">
        <Checkbox>Remember me</Checkbox>
      </Form.Item>

      <Form.Item {...tailLayout}>
        <Button type="primary" onClick={handleSubmit}>
          Submit
        </Button>
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  );
};
```

antd version: 4.10

Comment: doesn't the validateFields() call inside of your handleSubmit method do exactly what I'm trying to skip?

Comment: as i saied "if you comment entirely, There would be no error."

Comment: so you are suggesting to just run form.then((val) => { ... ??

Comment: comment form.validateFields().then.catch(). you can use this answer with empty handleSubmit function. i just added because maybe you need validating somewhere else.

Comment: you can play with answer in [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-usage-antd4102-forked-zkorh?file=/index.js)

Comment: some back and forth there with edits but this works.  Problem is that I already had this as a solution.  I'm looking more for if there is a prop of the Form component itself to the effect of skipValidationOnSubmit={true} or something....

Answer (score 0):

AntD (4.17.0) introduced the `warningOnly` property for validation rules.
If it is set to `true`, the form can be submitted even if that rule is violated.

Result: Orange warning will be shown in the UI (as opposed to red for an error) and the form will submit successfully.

Ref: https://codesandbox.io/s/mfm92l